# Can I create an SQL query such that Col A is my primary sort key but if the value is not NULL, Col B becomes my primary sort?

Tags: mysql, mariadb

Using MariaDB, I have a view that provides information including an eventdate and whether an invitation has been accepted. `eventdate` is of type `date` and is the date of the event. `accepted` is of type `tinyint` and contains 0 if the invitation has been declined, 1 if the invitation has been accepted, otherwise, it defaults to *NULL*.

I would like to develop a query sorted by `accepted`, and then `eventdate` so my *NULL* values will appear at the top of my list in `eventdate` order. However, if `accepted` is *NOT NULL* then I would like the data sorted by the `eventdate`.

My current query is:

`SELECT * FROM invite_view ORDER BY accepted, eventdate`

This, however, sorts the table so all `accepted = NULL` values are first, all *0* values are next, and finally, all *1* values are last, thusly:

```
eventname | eventdate  | accepted
---------------------------------
Event 1   | 2022-04-14 | NULL
Event 2   | 2022-04-25 | NULL
Event 3   | 2022-03-28 | 0
Event 4   | 2022-05-03 | 0
Event 5   | 2022-04-14 | 1
Event 6   | 2022-05-01 | 1
```

and I would like something like this:

```
eventname | eventdate  | accepted
---------------------------------
Event 1   | 2022-04-14 | NULL
Event 2   | 2022-04-25 | NULL
Event 3   | 2022-03-28 | 0
Event 5   | 2022-04-14 | 1
Event 6   | 2022-05-01 | 1
Event 4   | 2022-05-03 | 0
```

Comment: TIL `UNION` ignores the `ORDER BY` of the queries within it. Since that was going to be my answer but is wrong, I'll at least help you out with a little [fiddle with the data as you provided](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mariadb_10.3&fiddle=f8b1aabe901780349404154cf3d1270e).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way would be using CASE to sort the results conditionally

```
SELECT * 
FROM  invite_view 
ORDER BY CASE WHEN accepted IS NULL THEN accepted
              ELSE eventDate
         END
```

**Results:**

| id | eventname | eventdate | accepted |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | Event 1 | 2022-04-14 | *null* |
| 2 | Event 2 | 2022-04-25 | *null* |
| 3 | Event 3 | 2022-03-28 | 0 |
| 5 | Event 5 | 2022-04-14 | 1 |
| 6 | Event 6 | 2022-05-01 | 1 |
| 4 | Event 4 | 2022-05-03 | 0 |

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mariadb_10.3&fiddle=6198773ba7e1091bf7f0c27ac5f2f6ae)*

Comment: I had never heard of CASE in SQL. This was awesome! Thank you so much!

Comment: Glad it helped. See these links to read more about [CASE in Mariadb](https://mariadb.com/kb/en/case-statement/) or [CASE in MySQL](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/case.html).